# Magento2 - Create A Custom Report Displaying Order Items

Tags: magento-2.1, orders, customer, sales-order, reports

I'm trying to create a report that displays all order items along with some additional columns displaying things like customer name, customer billing address, order ID, payment method, etc.

**Can anyone provide any links to articles about creating a custom report in Magento2?**

**Or explain the best practices?**

I'm struggling to find any information on the subject.

Comment: Did you find solution?